# How to choose a specific data in a one2many list in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a one2many list that has fields like date, integers and etc. I just want to get the last record of the list.

Please help me, i am new to this language. I am using python for odoo.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Either modify the model

```
_order = 'create_date desc'#or _order = 'create_date asc'
```

or use **sorted** method over records

```
records.sorted(key=lambda r: r.create_date)[0]
#or records.sorted(key=lambda r: r.create_date)[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for this Prakash Sharma. Really appreciate.

Comment: def _get_contract_end_planned_date(self):
        list = self.env['loan.repayment.schedule.date_due']
        for records in list:
            records.max_record = records.sorted(key=lambda r: r.due_date)[0]

Comment: hi@Karen , if your query has been solved then please marked it answered.